# ionic sqlite database fail on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, ionic-framework

What could be wrong in this code?

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaSQLite, $timeout) {$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$rootScope.base = null;
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

if (window.cordova) {
  $rootScope.base = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "merial.db" }); //device
}
else {
  $rootScope.base = window.openDatabase("merial.db", '1', 'merial', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
}

$cordovaSQLite.execute($rootScope.base, "DROP TABLE `matching`;");
$cordovaSQLite.execute($rootScope.base, "CREATE TABLE `matching`(pool Text NOT NULL, type Text, topotype Text, couleur  Text,  souche Text );");});
```

Everything works in browser but on android or ios i can't find the database??

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use location default for device connection. This may solve your problem.

```
$rootScope.base = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "merial.db", location: 'default'}); //device
```

Comment: ok thank you, and if i have a pre-filled data-base i used this code:

 `$rootScope.base= window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase( {name: "merial.db", createFromLocation: 1} );` 
but it doesn't work as well, any suggestions for that?

Comment: Thank you, I've never used pre-filled before.